# g++ mudflap on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I have some issues with mudflap. I'm still getting "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmudflap" error, but I've already installed libmudflap using Synaptic Package Manager. How to correctly install mudflap? I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Mudflap is old and useless. Use valgrind instead.

Answer (score 3):

It always the same: to run agains library `foo`, you need `libfoo`.  But to *compile* using `foo`, you also need `libfoo-dev`.

For `mudflap`, these are also compiler-dependent, so you want one of these:

- `libmudflap0-4.3-dev`
- `libmudflap0-4.4-dev`
- `libmudflap0-4.5-dev`

depending on which compiler you use.

Comment: I had libmudflap0-4.4-dev and libmudflap0-4.5-dev but I forgot to install libmudflap0-4.3-dev. Now I have a lots of errors about some missing refferenecs for example: "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libmudflap.a(mf-hooks1.o): In function `__wrap_munmap':
(.text.__wrap_munmap+0x65): undefined reference to `__real_munmap'
"